# Event-based-microservices: MQTT with Broker OR HTTP with API GATEWAY?

Tags: rest, mqtt, publish-subscribe, broker

I'm trying to develop a project with microservices.

I have some questions on this topic (something is not clear):

**1)** How to implement microservices communication?

A) HTTP : Every microservice expose HTTP API , an API GATEWAY broadcast requests.

B) MQTT : every microservice pub/sub to a broker

C) BOTH : but how to understand when one is better than the other ?

Have I to use pub/sub protocol as a standard even for classic operations usually performed over HTTP ? For example I have two microservices:
**web-management** and **product-service**. **web-management** is a panel that lets the administrator to add, modify, ... products in its ecommerce digital shop. Let's say we want to implement createProduct operation. It's a **command** (according to event /command distinction), a one-to-one communication.

I can open an API in product-service, let's say (POST, "/product") that add the new product. I also can implement this transforming the command in a **productCreationRequest** event. In this case: **web-managemnet** publish this event. **product-service** listen to **productCreationRequest** events (and also productUpdateRequest, productGetEvents, ...) once it is notified it performs the operation and emits **productCreated** event.

I find this case borderline. For example a **last-occasion-service** may listen to **productCreated** and immediately send a message (email or push notification) to customers. What do you think about this use case?

2) Which may be a valid broker (I will use docker-compose or kubernetes to orchestrate containerized microservices: language adopted probably java, javascript, python)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both is definitely a possibility!  Choose a broker that allows you to easily mix-and-match between HTTP (synchronous) communication, and more async event-driven pub/sub.  It should allow you to migrate your microservices between the two options as required.

HTTP APIs are great at the edge of your distributed application, where a customer wants to submit an order or something, and *block* waiting for a response (200 OK).

But internally within your application between microservices, a lot of them don't need a response... async, eventually consistent.  And using pub/sub (like MQTT) allows for multiple downstream consumers easily.  Another great use for MQTT is streaming updates to downstream consumers... like a data-feed from a bus or airline company or something, rather than having to *poll* a REST API for updates.

For your use-case and similar ones, I would almost always recommend using pub/sub communication, even if today it's a simple request-reply interaction with a single backend process.  REST over HTTP is point-to-point, and perhaps in the future you want another process to be able to see/consume/monitor that event or interaction.  If you're already using publish-subscribe, adding that 2nd (or more) consumer of that data flow is trivial.  Harder with REST/HTTP.

In terms of performance, I would highly doubt a blocking protocol like HTTP is going to outperform something that is asynchronous and bidirectional, like MQTT which uses WebSockets for web communication.

As for a broker to glue all this together, check out the standard edition Solace PubSub+ event broker... can do both (and translate between) MQTT and HTTP.  I even wrote a [CodeLab for this (almost) exact use case](https://codelabs.solace.dev/codelabs/solace-event-enable-rest) haha!

(BTW, I work for Solace! FYI.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using SMF framework for Javascript/Node.js, it helps prototype pub/sub communications via a message broker (RabbitMQ) between microservices out of the box:

https://medium.com/@krawa76/bootstrap-node-js-microservice-stack-4a348db38e51

As for the message broker routes, use an event-driven naming convention, e.g. post a "web.new-product", where "web" is the sub-system name, "new-product" - event name.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! It is really helpful, And what about performance for this specific case? Does mqtt and http behave similar?

Comment: I doubt you'll notice any performance differences for this case.

Comment: Thank you @Serge you clarify my doubts!